# error when get value from array preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I faced some problem when I get second array value and pass it to a variable.

```
array:0 [
    "student_id" => 1212
    "class" => array:1 [
     "id" => 550
      ]
    ]
```

Normally `$student= array_get($data, 'student_id');`
able to get value.

Now I'm trying to get class id something like `$class= array_get($data, 'class', 'id');`
but it pop-up this error;

Comment: What error? What `preg_replace`?

Comment: @user3783243 [array_get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-get) is a laravel helper function. I suppose it uses preg_replace under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get values from nested array use the *dot* notation.

`$class = array_get($data, 'class.id');`